# How can I use a loop to write a redundant Rmarkdown script?

Tags: r, loops, automation, r-markdown

I'm creating a Markdown file to generate 32 statistical tables. I'd like to automate it. The statistical tables are stored in a list. Here's a fictitious representation of my list of tables.

```
mylist<-list(
fruits=data.frame(fruit=c("Apple","Mango","Banana"),
                   number=c(45,100,70)),

animals=data.frame(animal=c("Monkey","Lion","Whale","Raven"),
                    number=c(100,2,20,60)),

countries=data.frame(country=c("France","Senegal","China"),
                      number=c(200,75,1000)),

cars=data.frame(car=c("Audi","Peugeot","Porsche","Toyota","Alpha Romeo"),
                 number=c(5,7,18,2,8)))


saveRDS(mylist, file = "mylist.RDS")
```

Here's the Markdown script I used to generate my results:

````
---
TEtitle: R
author: "MYNAME"
date: "2024-02-16"
output:
  word_document: default
  html_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE)
```


```{r}
mylist<-readRDS("mylist.RDS")
library(knitr)
```



# Statistics on `r names(mylist)[1]`


```{r}
kable(mylist[[1]])
```



# Statistics on `r names(mylist)[2]`


```{r}
kable(mylist[[2]])
```


# Statistics on `r names(mylist)[3]`


```{r}
kable(mylist[[3]])
```


# Statistics on `r names(mylist)[4]`


```{r}
kable(mylist[[4]])
```
````

To automate with a loop that is what I tried, hoping to reproduce the code above. It didn't work. I have no other ideas. Can someone please help me.

````
`r for (i in seq_along(mylist)) {
  cat("# Statistics on `r names(mylist)[", i, "]`\n\n")
  cat("```{r}\n")
  cat("kable(mylist[[", i, "]])\n")
  cat("```\n\n")
`
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `for` loop in a code chunk for which you set the chunk option `results='asis'`. Here is a working solution to achieve your desired result.

````
---
TEtitle: R
author: "MYNAME"
date: "2024-02-16"
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE)

library(knitr)
```


```{r}
mylist <- list(
  fruits = data.frame(
    fruit = c("Apple", "Mango", "Banana"),
    number = c(45, 100, 70)
  ),
  animals = data.frame(
    animal = c("Monkey", "Lion", "Whale", "Raven"),
    number = c(100, 2, 20, 60)
  ),
  countries = data.frame(
    country = c("France", "Senegal", "China"),
    number = c(200, 75, 1000)
  ),
  cars = data.frame(
    car = c("Audi", "Peugeot", "Porsche", "Toyota", "Alpha Romeo"),
    number = c(5, 7, 18, 2, 8)
  )
)
```

```{r results='asis'}
for (i in seq_along(mylist)) {
  cat("# Statistics on `", names(mylist)[i], "`\n\n")
  print(kable(mylist[[i]]))
  cat("\n\n")
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: That solution is just brilliant. Thanks